# vue js and strapi - console says property is undefined but it's not - it renders on the page

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, strapi

Why would something like this happen?

I have a vue app that is pointing to a strapi CMS instance and is consuming the API to render on the page.

I changed my backend query slightly and the response is a little different so I have to go array index 0 to it (`{{ webinar[0].webinar_title }}` ) but for some reason it says it's undefined, even though it still renders on the page:

```
<template>
    <section class="webinar-information">
        <div>
          <h1>{{ webinar[0].webinar_title }}</h1>
          <p>{{ webinar[0].webinar_description }}</p>
        </div>
    </section>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  name: 'WebinarSingle',
  data () {
    return {
      webinar: [],
      error: null
    }
  },
  async mounted () {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:1337/webinars?webinar_slug=' + `${this.$route.params.id}`)
      this.webinar = response.data
      console.log(this.webinar)
      // this is returning the title why is it "undefined" in the console?
      console.log('the title is: ' + this.webinar[0].webinar_title)
    } catch (error) {
      this.error = error;
    }
  },
  props: {
    header: String
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

The output is correct and looks like this:

[image]

But my console is this:

[image]

The output of

`http://localhost:1337/webinars?webinar_slug=' +` ${this.$route.params.id}``

is:

http://localhost:1337/webinars?webinar_slug=accelerating-the-close-with-technology-and-automation

When you console log the response it looks like this:

[image]

so I have to access everything by doing `[0]` with it "working" but the console says it's undefined. why?

Comment: it doesnt initialy exist `webinar: [],`, so do `<section v-if="webinar.length" class="webinar-information">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the page loads, Vue tries to render your template:

```
<template>
    <section class="webinar-information">
        <div>
          <h1>{{ webinar[0].webinar_title }}</h1>
          <p>{{ webinar[0].webinar_description }}</p>
        </div>
    </section>
</template>
```

At this point in time, `webinar` is what you initialised it with, i.e. `[]`. When you try to access the first element, this causes your error.

Then X milliseconds later, `localhost:1337` returns the response that displays.

To fix your problem, you can add a `v-if="webinar && webinar.length"` to the root element in your template (not the template element), then it will only try access `webinar[0]` when there is an element.

Comment: Got it, so is that a best practice to do, wait until it's full rendered with a conditional?

Comment: It depends on the situation, sometimes I would prefer to do `{{ (webinar && webinar.length ? webinar[0].webinar_title : "-") }}` so that some of the page still renders and then just the text changes.